# Django: saving username by default in a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I´m trying to build a task manager. I should have a field for the creator user and another for the destination user.

I realized that I can´t define 2 foreign key fields pointing to the same users list, so I have the destination user field as a foreign for the creator user to choose and then I´m trying to set the active user name as the creator in views.

The form stores all the collected data but not the one set in the view. I get no error, but the value is not saved.

**The model**

```
class Tareas(models.Model):
    creador = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Creador", blank=True, null=True)
    destinatario = models.ForeignKey(User, help_text="Estatus del contenido", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Título de la tarea", blank=True, null=True)
    tarea = models.TextField(max_length=500, help_text="Explicación de la tarea", blank=True, null=True)
    resuelto = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateField(help_text="Fecha de creación", default=datetime.date.today, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_limite = models.DateField(help_text="Fecha límite", default=datetime.date.today, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_resuelto = models.DateField(help_text="Fecha de resolución", default=datetime.date.today, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.titulo)
```

**The form**

```
class FormularioTareas(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tareas
        widgets = {'fecha_limite': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'})}
        fields = ["destinatario", "titulo", "tarea", "resuelto", "fecha_limite", "creador", "fecha_creacion"]
```

**The view**

```
@login_required
def TareasView(request):

    tareas_form = FormularioTareas(request.POST)
    tareas = Tareas.objects.all()
    tareas = tareas.order_by("-fecha_creacion")

    if request.method == "POST":
        tareas_form = FormularioTareas(request.POST)
        if tareas_form.is_valid():
            tarea = tareas_form.save(commit=False)
            tarea.creador = request.user.username
            tarea.fecha_creacion = date.today()
            tarea.save()

    return render(request, 'catalog/tareas.html', {
        'tareas_form': tareas_form,
        'tareas': tareas
    })
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't have two ForeignKeys pointing to the same model? Of course you can. Just make sure the `related_name` fields are different so that the reverse relationship works.

Comment: Also you can't set values on `cleaned_data` and expect them to be saved, that's not how a ModelForm works. You should just first fetch the instance with `save(commit=False)`, then directly set the attributes (e.g. `tarea.creador = request.user`) and then `save()`.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten I updated the question with the changes in the view, still not getting the values saved.

Comment: When you say the values are not saved you mean just `creador` is not set or the entire model is not saved?

Comment: Only "Creador", the values already comming with the form are sabved correctly.

Comment: Note that I told you to set `tarea.creador = request.user` assuming you'd change it to a ForeignKey, if it's still just a CharField, you should use `request.user.username`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I just updated the question with the "request.user.username" and is still not saving the name.

Comment: That's not possible if it actually runs those lines. Set a breakpoint or `print(request.user.username)` before that line to see what's going on.

Comment: It´s working now. Thanks @dirkgroten